# Field name in form is truncated in Dynamics CRM 2016

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, crm, dynamics-crm-2016

I have created a custom entity and I have some new fields created.
Ex: **StudentCarrierTypeInformation**  (field name)

**datatype**: single line of text

I put this field on the form, and when I see this in the front end of the form, the field name is truncated.

It is like **StudentCarrierTy**. The rest of the name is truncated in the form.

I think its label has length only 20 I guess.

Is there a way to display the field name which is longer as I have above?

Answer (score 4):

I was able to fix this myself. I navigated to the the form and went to the field properties and edited the same to 200 pixels.

Answer (score 2):

You can set the **Field label width** from **Section properties**. Default is 115 (shown below) and Maximum is 250.

[image]

After making changes to 250, If label text is still hiding - then use the **Field label position** in **Formatting tab** of **Section properties**.

[image]

Tooltip will show full text in any case.